# State is not updating with AsyncStorage value

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm creating an android app with **react-navtive**. I'm using `Asyncstorage` to authenticate  login info.Here is my code:

**Login.js**

```
const Login =()=>{
  const history=useHistory();
  const [state,setState] =useState({
    username:'',
    password:'',
  });
   const findUser=()=>{
      const data=new FormData();
          data.append('username',state.username);
          data.append('password',state.password);
  fetch(url,{
    method:'POST',

    body:data
  })
  .then(response=>response.json())
  .then(async res=>{

    if(res.status==="true"){
     await Asyncstorage.setItem('customer',state.username);    
     if(res.acType=="user"){
      history.push("/user")

    }else{
      history.push("/owner")
    }
    }
  });
  }
  return //return codes goes here
}
export default Login;
```

**Authenticate.js**

```
const AuthScreen=()=>{
    const[state,setState]=useState({
            isLogedIn:true
         });

    useEffect(()=>{
        async function checkLogin(){
            const data=await AsyncStorage.getItem('customer');
            return data;
        }
        checkLogin().then(name=>{

            console.log((name));
            if(name==null){
               setState({isLogedIn:false})
            }
            else{
                setState({isLogedIn:true})
            }
            console.log(state.isLogedIn)
        }
        )
    });
    if(state.isLogedIn==false){
        return <Redirect to="/login"/>
    }
    else{
        return <Redirect to="/user" />
    }
  }
```

The problem is that the `isLoggedIn` state is not updating its value when the value of `name` (**Authenticate.js**) is null

Answer (score 0):

Check the typeof name I think it's string and you are comparing it will data type null.
Put conditions i.e if(name == 'null' )
It will solve your problem

in console what you are of name
console.log((name));

Comment: I used with if(name == 'null') but still the problem persist

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got answer.I used just **useState()** instead of **useState({isLoggedIn:true})**

and updated value with true or false directly.I don't know what is the difference  but it worked for  me